# Spring Integration and JAXB scope

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, spring-integration

I am asking a general question about how JAXB will maintain the values associated with the generated class.  I can generate the class, use it as long as it is in the payload, but when I move on to another spring integration process the object doesn't appear to retain those values.  I know there must be an easy way to make sure the generated object retains what it was populated with.  I can re-instantiate the class and but that is just a new empty class.

Here is sort of what I am trying to accomplish

A basic XML document to be generated

```
<ElementA>
        <Element1>Value1</Element1>
        <Element2>Value2</Element2>
        <Element3>
            <ElementYY>ValueYY</ElementYY>
        </Element3>
</ElementA>
<ElementB>ElementBValue</ElementB>
```

This will generate

```
    JAXBGeneratedClass
```

However I choose to get this xml can be used then I unmarshal it

```
    <!--  JAXB UnMarshalling transformer to generate object from XML -->    
<int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer 
    id="unmarshallMessage"
    unmarshaller="xmlMarshaller"
    input-channel="input-channel"
    output-channel="output-channel" />
```

I then have other Spring Integration components in the process flow until I get to a router where I want to use a POJO to evaluate it

```
    <!--  Route it accordingly -->
<int:router 
    id="jaxb-router"
    input-channel="input-router-channel"
    ref="evaluationClass"
    method="evaluateAction"
    default-output-channel="discard-channel">
        <int:mapping value="new" channel="new-channel" />
        <int:mapping value="update" channel="update-channel" />
        <int:mapping value="duplicate" channel="duplicate-channel" />
        <int:mapping value="error" channel="error-channel" />
</int:router>
```

This is where I cannot get the object value, it doesn't seem to retain what it once had.

```
@Component("evaluationClass")
public class EvaluationClass {
     final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(EvaluationClass.class);

     JAXBGeneratedClass myObject;

     public String evaluateAction(Message<?> message) {

          /*Use values from myObject*/
          /*Do comparison on the message using mObject*/

         if (myObject.getElementA().getElement3().getElementYY() 
                     != message.getPayload().value) {
          /* Evaluation */
         }
        return statusValue;
       }
    }
```

I have figured out a couple of ways to accomplish it so I am not stuck on this but it is bugging me.  Why doesn't the object retain it's value? Or is there something in the JAXB bean that I can turn on or configure.  I have researched it and tried a lot of things to no avail.

Dave

Here is the Unmarshaller

```
    <!--  JAXB unmarshalling Transformer bean -->  
<bean id="xmlMarshaller" name="xmlMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list value-type="java.lang.Class">
            <value>org.agency.schema.jmsupdateservice.ObjectFactory</value>
            <value>org.agency.schema.jmsupdateservice.CourtCaseInitiatedNotificationMsg</value>
            <value>org.agency.schema.CourtCaseInitiatedNotification</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schema" value="classpath:schemas/JMSUpdateService.xsd" />
</bean>
```

I originally just had the ObjectFactory in the value list.

Payload:

```
[Payload CourtCaseInitiatedNotificationMsg content=org.agency.schema.jmsupdateservice.CourtCaseInitiatedNotificationMsg@6671e17f][Headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, JMSXUserID=jsg589      , JMS_IBM_Encoding=546, history=caseNumber-inbound-adapter,caseNumber-source-channel,caseNumber-inbound-source-log-service,caseNumber-source-message-logged-channel,caseNumber-xslt-transform,caseNumber-xsltTransform-channel,caseNumber-inbound-filter-valid,caseNumber-xsltTransform-valid-channel,unmarshallCaseNumber,caseNumber-jaxb-channel,caseNumber-jaxb-payload-service,caseNumber-payload-persisted-channel, priority=0, jms_timestamp=1409774002830, JMSXAppID=WebSphere MQ Client for Java, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20140903, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, JMS_IBM_PutTime=19532283, jms_messageId=ID:414d51204843534f4445564c2e514d4753f24b622007b203, id=f13a0b5b-1e96-394d-e2fa-8578de021f7a, timestamp=1409774011053}]
```

I can use the object when it is the payload, but after that it doesn't retain the value in the CourtCaseInitiatedNotificationMsg.  If I try to reference that object, it is null.  Shouldn't it still be available for use?

I know that this is different from what I posted because I was just wondering about the scope of the JAXB class and how long, or if it does retain the values that it once had when it was a payload.  Is this still accessible -> org.agency.schema.jmsupdateservice.CourtCaseInitiatedNotificationMsg@6671e17f later in the context and can I use it in a POJO?

Thank you again for your help.

Dave

Comment: Please show your `xmlMarshaller` config.

Comment: Please, show your `message.getPayload()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can overcome your requirement with `MessageHeaders`. Justplace your `original` payload to headers and use it after `marshaller`. That's because the `payload` of message is changed after each `transformer`. Be careful, though, when your payload is mutable, so, your object in the headers will be changed too.

Comment: That is what I did on one version.  Another version I used a service activator and assigned the payload values to a class.  That is what I am using right now.  I was just curious if I was missing something or there was a configuration that I was lacking.  Thank you Artem and Gary.